# How to define a matrix with all elements 0?

Tags: matrix, variable-definitions

A matrix can be defined as

```
M = Array[m, {3, 3}]
```

which gives

```
{{m[1, 1], m[1, 2], m[1, 3]}, {m[2, 1], m[2, 2], m[2, 3]}, {m[3, 1], m[3, 2], m[3, 3]}}
```

How to give all `m[i, j]` the value `0` (if `M` is a `NxN` matrix)?

Comment: `ConstantArray[0,{3,3}]`, `SparseArray[{},{3,3}]`. `m[[;;,;;]]=0`.

Comment: And `Array[0 &, {3, 3}]`

Comment: Expanding on Oska's comment, if you simply *define* `m[i_,j_]=0`, then you'll get the array you want, since `Array` produces an `array` with elements `m[i,j]`. Oska did essentially this using a pure function.

Comment: Also: `0 BoxMatrix[1]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Summarizing what has been said in the comments.

You can create a zero matrix by many ways:

```
ClearAll[n, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, size]
size[n_] := {n, n}
n = 3;
m1 = ConstantArray[0, size[n]];
m2 = SparseArray[{}, size[n]];
m3 = Module[{mm = Array[m, size[n]]}, mm[[;; , ;;]] = 0; mm];
m4 = Module[{m}, m[i_, j_] = 0; Array[m, size[n]]];
m5 = 0 Array[,size[n]];
m6 = Array[0 &, size[n]];
m7 = Table[0, {#}, {#2}] & @@ size[n];
m8 = ArrayReshape[{0}, size[n]];
m9 = 0*BoxMatrix@1

m1 == m2 == m3 == m4 == m5 == m6 == m7 == m8 == m9
```

> ```
> True
> ```

With a speed priority given to `SparseArray[{}, size[n]]`.

```
m1 // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}\right)$