# How can I expand a matrix and fill in zeros?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Given a square matrix like

```
m = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

I want to expand it to a 5x5 matrix

```
k = {{1,2,3,0,0},{4,5,6,0,0},{7,8,9,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1}};
```

In MATLAB, one can do

```
m[[4,4]]=1; 
m[[5,5]]=1;
```

which also automatically "fills in" the zeros.

Comment: Check `SparseArray` documentation

Comment: SparseArray will not do it ether.

Comment: Don't discount @yarchik 's advice:  `SparseArray[m, {5, 5}, 0] // Normal`.

Comment: It seems to me that an important point here is whether you want to expand `m` ('in-place modification'), and which I suspect MATLAB is doing, or whether you want to create a new matrix `k`.  For in-place modification, maybe `m//=MapAt[1&,{{4,4},{5,5}}]@ArrayPad[#,{0,2}]&` (using `ApplyTo`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really do that in Mathematica as the new position must be there already.  Btw, I never really like this feature in Matlab. I do not think it is good. Because someone by mistake could do this, using wrong index, and not know about it, as Matlab will silently expands the matrix. In Mathematica you get a real error message, which is much better.

Explicit is always better than implicit when it comes to coding.

But easy enough to make your own little expand function.

```
(m={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}})//MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
myExpand[m,4]//MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
myExpand[m,5]//MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
myExpand[m, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
myExpand[m, 8] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### code

```
myExpand[mat_?MatrixQ, (newSize_Integer)?Positive] := 
 Module[{t, currentSize = Length@mat},
  If[newSize <= currentSize,
   t = mat[[1 ;; newSize, 1 ;; newSize]]
   ,
   t = Table[0, {newSize}, {newSize}];
   t[[1 ;; currentSize, 1 ;; currentSize]] = mat 
   ];
  t
  ]
```

ps. If you wanted 1 on diagonal and not zeros, then just replace the line

```
t = Table[0, {newSize}, {newSize}];
```

with

```
t = IdentityMatrix[newSize];
```

so now `myExpand[m, 5] // MatrixForm` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see from the others answers, in Mathematica, there are always at least 10 different ways to do the same thing, and you pick the one that you prefer most.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.

Comment: You can also just use `ArrayPad` or `PadRight`.

Comment: Is there a reason for `Table[0, {newSize}, {newSize}]` instead of `ConstantArray[0,newSize,newSize]` ? (except that ConstantArray still is not compileable)

Comment: @JulienKluge No reason., There are at least 10 different ways to make a matrix of zeros. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47642/how-to-define-a-matrix-with-all-elements-0)  and I just picked one that seemed most easy for general public :)

Answer (score 8):

See the docs for [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)

```
k = ArrayFlatten[{{m, 0}, 
                  {0, IdentityMatrix[2]}}];
k // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: hi. fyi, op wanted to expand with all zeros.

Comment: `k = ArrayFlatten[{{m, 0}, {0, ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}]}}];`

Comment: @Syed & Nasser Thank you for your comments, but I see 1's on the diagonal in the OP.  The OP shows an example of trying to insert the 1's using MMA's double square-bracket notation, but in the Matlab syntax.  The OP does mention automatic filling in the zeros, but those zeros are in the 4th and 5th rows and columns, *not on the diagonal*.

Comment: You might be right. I just read the title of the question saying "fill with zeros". But now looking at it more, may they wanted like you show. I'll update a note to my answer now just in case.

Answer (score 8):

```
BlockDiagonalMatrix[{m, IdentityMatrix[2]}]
```

To get a "normal" matrix:

```
Normal[BlockDiagonalMatrix[{m, IdentityMatrix[2]}]]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 0, 0}, 
    {4, 5, 6, 0, 0}, 
    {7, 8, 9, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```

If your example was just accidentally a diagonal block matrix, and all you need is to pad out a matrix with zeros to get a certain size which you will then update, then you can just use `ArrayPad` or `PadRight`:

```
ArrayPad[m, {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

or

```
PadRight[m, {5, 5}]
```

Of course, these don't update `m`, so if part of your question was updating, then just redefine m:

```
m = ArrayPad[m, {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

or

```
m = PadRight[m, {5, 5}]
```

To your comment that "SparseArray will not do it", I have to disagree. The following will give you a sparse array version of your padded `m`:

```
SparseArray[m, {5, 5}]
```

or

```
m = SparseArray[m, {5, 5}]
```

With the latter, you can now do

```
m[[4,4]] = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
MapAt[1 &, ArrayPad[m, {0, 2}], {{4, 4}, {5, 5}}]
```

or

```
ReplaceAt[ArrayPad[m, {0, 2}], _ :> 1, {{4, 4}, {5, 5}}]
```

and

```
ReplacePart[ArrayPad[m, {0, 2}], {4, 4} | {5, 5} :> 1]
```

give

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) + [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html) to modify the dimensions and specify/modify entries of an input matrix in a single step:

```
ClearAll[modifyArray]

modifyArray = SparseArray[Append[#2, Band[{1, 1}] -> {#}], ##3] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
m = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

rules = {{2, 1} -> 100, {4, 4} -> FOO, {5, 5} -> BAR, {6, 2} -> 62};

modifyArray[m, rules]// MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
modifyArray[m, rules, {8, 7}]  // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
modifyArray[m, rules, Automatic, Z]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
myMatExpand[mat_?MatrixQ, nsize_Integer?Positive]/; Length[mat] < nsize := 
Flatten[Reap[
Do[Sow[Join[l, Array[0 &, nsize - Length@mat]]], {l, mat}];
Do[Sow[ReplacePart[Array[0 &, nsize], i -> 1]], {i, Take[Range[nsize], 
Length[mat] - nsize]}];][[2]], 1]
```

Testing `myMatExpand`:

```
myMatExpand[m, 8] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Another way is as follows:

```
myMatExpand[mat_?MatrixQ, nsize_Integer?Positive] /; 
Length[mat] < nsize := Join[Map[Join[#, Array[0 &, nsize - Length@mat]] &, mat], 
Take[IdentityMatrix[nsize], Length@mat - nsize]]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

```
expandMatrix[m_?MatrixQ, list_?VectorQ] := 
 Flatten[#, 1] &@MapIndexed[#2 -> #1 &, m, {2}]~Join~list // 
   SparseArray // Normal
```

**Usage:**

```
expandMatrix[m, {{4, 4} -> 1, {5, 5} -> 1}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**"You can use 1 or 0 in diagonal: "**

```
ExpandM[m_,n_,k_]:=(d=Dimensions[m][[1]];(Table[If[j ≤ d ,a=m[[j]];Do[a=Insert[a,0,i],{i,d+1,n}];a,Insert[ConstantArray[0,n-1],k,j]],{j,1,n}])//MatrixForm)
```

**Diagonal 1 :**

```
ExpandM[m,5,1]
```

[image]

**Diagonal 0 :**

```
ExpandM[m,5,0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]